# Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached while testing my Guzzle client?

Tags: php, recursion, phpunit, runtime-error, guzzle

My very basic understanding of [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) internals maybe the cause of this error (PHPUnit test):

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,
>   aborting! in
>   \vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\QueryString.php
>   on line 234

It seems that the following sections (plugin and parser) are calling each other. The **plugin** is listening for `command.before_send` event, adding a closure as listener for the `request.exception` event:

```
/**
 * The plugin adds a closure listener for the event 'response.exception'. The
 * closure is using the parser (RestInterfaceParser).
 */
class ResponseListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array('command.before_send' => 'onCommandBeforeSend');
    }

    public function onCommandBeforeSend(Event $event)
    {
        // ...
        $command = $event['command'];
        $request = $command->getRequest();

        $request->getEventDispatcher()->addListener(
            'request.exception',
            function (Event $event) use ($command, $parser) {
                $parsed = $parser->parse($command);

                // ...
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Nothing special so far! The error is caused by the **parser**, when I try to access the response object:

```
/**
 * The parser invoked by the closure listener.
 */
class RestInterfaceParser implements ResponseParserInterface
{
    public function parse(CommandInterface $command)
    {
        var_dump($command->getResponse());
    }
}
```

Removing that line removes the error. But, big surprise, I need the response object inside the parser. Increasing the nesting level (`xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000`) doesn't help because it's "pure" recursion here.

Comment: Are you sure you are dealing exactly with the object you are expecting? Dump the object, not only the result of `getResponse()`. And do more debugging. The problem with understanding your question is that there is much more going on in code we do not see. And actually I have NO idea where the interfaces and classes do come from that you use.

Comment: @Sven I've found a solution (I've already posted the answer)... and yes, I was NOT dealing with the command object properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution looking at class [`DefaultResponseParser`](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/DefaultResponseParser.php):

```
$command->getRequest()->getResponse();
```

Is the correct way to accessing the response object. Quite confusing indeed.

Comment: Yes, this will work. The reason you are seeing infinite recursion is because a response is only set on a command object when a request succeeds. Otherwise, it attempts to send the request again. You can also use the `response` context value of the Event that is emitted by the `request.exception` event.

Comment: @MichaelDowling thank you for confirming this. Mind if I ask you to help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705907/changing-parameter-values-of-guzzle-commands-at-runtime-through-plugins