# Changing parameter values of Guzzle commands at runtime, through plugins?

Tags: php, guzzle

This is (part of) the definition of `BaseOperation`, with one mandatory parameter (`foo`):

```
'BaseOperation' => array(
    'class' => 'My\Command\MyCustomCommand',
    'httpMethod' => 'POST',
    'parameters' => array(
        'foo' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'location' => 'query'
        )
    )
)
```

Inside `ChangeMethodPlugin` plugin I need to modify the value of `foo` at runtime:

```php
class ChangeMethodPlugin implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array('command.before_send' => 'onBeforeCommandSend');
    }

    public function onBeforeCommandSend(Event $event)
    {
        /** @var \Guzzle\Service\Command\CommandInterface $command */
        $command = $event['command'];

        // Only if test configuration is true
        if ($command->getClient()->getConfig(ClientOptions::TEST)) {
            // Only if command is MyCustomCommand
            if ($command instanceof MyCustomCommand) {
                // Here I need to change the value of 'foo' parameter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find any method inside [`Parameter`](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Service/Description/Parameter.php) or [`AbstractCommand`](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/AbstractCommand.php).

**EDIT**: param name changed to "foo" from "method" to avoid confusion with HTTP verbs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setHttpMethod()` method of the Operation owned by the command, but you'll need to use the `command.before_prepare` event instead.

```
<?php

class ChangeMethodPlugin implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array('command.before_prepare' => 'onBeforeCommandPrepare');
    }

    public function onBeforeCommandPrepare(Event $event)
    {
        /** @var \Guzzle\Service\Command\CommandInterface $command */
        $command = $event['command'];

        // Only if test configuration is true
        if ($command->getClient()->getConfig(ClientOptions::TEST)) {
            // Only if command is MyCustomCommand
            if ($command instanceof MyCustomCommand) {
                // Here I need to change the value of 'method' parameter
                $command->getOperation()->setHttpMethod('METHOD_NAME');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the param name is confusing. I'm not talking about the HTTP method itself, but about a param named "method". I'm going to edit the question...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

`$command->getRequest()->getQuery()->set('foo', 'bar');`

So long as you have injected the new 'foo' value into the plugin, you should be able to accomplish what you are looking to do.